# Accessing the values of surrounding cells in a dataframe without using a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to calculate for each cell in a dataframe the sum of the values of all surrounding cells (including in diagonal), without using a loop.

I have come up with something that looks like that, but it does not include diagonals, and as soon as I include diagonals some cells are counted too many times.

```
# Initializing matrix a
columns = [x for x in range(10)]
rows = [x for x in range(10)]
matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=rows, columns=columns).fillna(0)

# filling up with mock values
matrix.iloc[5,4] = 1
matrix.iloc[5,5] = 1
matrix.iloc[5,6] = 1
matrix.iloc[4,5] = 1

matrix1 = matrix.apply(lambda x: x.shift(1)).fillna(0)
matrix2 = matrix.T.apply(lambda x: x.shift(1)).T.fillna(0)
matrix3 = matrix.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1)).fillna(0)
matrix4 = matrix.T.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1)).T.fillna(0)

matrix_out = matrix1 + matrix2 + matrix3 + matrix4
```

To be more precise, I plan on populating the dataframe only with 0 or 1 values. The test above is the following:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The expected output for this input is:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  3  3  4  2  1  0
5  0  0  0  1  2  3  3  1  1  0
6  0  0  0  1  3  3  3  2  1  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Am I in the right direction with this shift() function used within apply, or would you suggest doing otherwise?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would be useful if you posted the expected output for this input

Comment: it looks like you are trying to calculate the convolution of a dataframe with a kernel of size 3 with 1 everywhere except a 0 in the center. You can use the numpy convolve or scipy.signal.sepfir2d

Comment: Thank you @Alexis I will look into this...

Comment: @zelig shouldn't `row=4,col=6` hold value `4` instead of `3`?

Comment: @RafaelC absolutely, my bad... Corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
def sum_diag(matrix):
    return matrix.shift(1,axis=1).shift(1, axis=0) + matrix.shift(-1, axis=1).shift(1, axis=0) + matrix.shift(1, axis=1).shift(-1) + matrix.shift(-1, axis=1).shift(-1, axis=0)

def sum_nxt(matrix):
    return matrix.shift(-1) + matrix.shift(1) + matrix.shift(1,axis=1) + matrix.shift(-1, axis=1)

final = sum_nxt(matrix) + sum_diag(matrix)
```

Outputs

```
print(final.fillna(0).astype(int))


    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   1   3   3   4   2   1   0
5   0   0   0   1   2   3   3   1   1   0
6   0   0   0   1   2   3   3   2   1   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Notice that you might want to add `.fillna(0)` to all `shift` operations to ensure the borders behave well too, if numbers in the borders are not zero.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! I had tried with the 'axis' parameter in the shift() functions but I kept trying within the apply...